# Path returned from Process.MainModule.Filename

Tags: c#, .net

```
string odd = ProcessGetProcessesByName("winlogon")[0].MainModule.FileName;
```

The return string is added with `??` as in `\??\C:\Windows\system32\winlogon.exe`

I wonder what is that `?` and why a similar process's exe path query done to any other processes does not result strings with `\??\` as their prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Long Path](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx) if I am not mistaken.